# Couldn't get started with clojure kORMa

Tags: mysql, clojure, compojure, korma

I am trying to use clojure kORMa with compojure, the webapp is here [nepleaks](https://github.com/iPrayag/nepleaks/blob/master/src/hotel/conf/datasource.clj).

First I added kORMa dependency

```
[korma "0.3.0-RC4"]
```

`lein deps` works cool, then created `src/hotel/conf/datasource.clj` which looks as follows :

```
(ns hotel.conf.datasource)
   (use [korma.db])
   (use [korma.core])
)

(defdb db (mysql {:db "nepleaks"
                     :user "root"
                     :password "mysql55"}))

(defentity users)
```

`lein ring server` is neither throwing any exception nor creating the database entity.

**Am I missing something?** Do I need more configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that Korma does not create the database nor the database tables for you, so you need to create them beforehand manually.

Comment: Ughh..didn't know that.Then what (defentity) actually does? Just mapping the entities? Would like to ask whether  https://github.com/budu/lobos helps on creating database tables as it describes itself as "a comprehensive DDL DSL."

Comment: @PrayagUpd Yes, it just maps the entities. You could Lobos or lein-dbmaintain (https://github.com/mysema/lein-dbmaintain) which is a wrapper for DbMaintain. Disclaimer: lein-dbmaintain is maintained by the company I work at.

Comment: Great, m starting to work on lobo :). If got any problems with that, then will think of lein-dbmaintain.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of an example being worth 1000 words, I would recommend checking out the luminus clojure web framework. See http://www.luminusweb.net/ This framework sets up a lot of really useful libraries with very basic example use, including korma, ragtime, ring, compojure and some other nice libs. The default templates show you lots of nice ways of using these libraries and how to integrate them. You can then pick the bits you want. All you need to do to get started is run

```
lein new luminus <your project> +mysql
```

The web site has good documentation and the code is pretty clean and easy to understand. Saves hours when wanting to get up and running with a new library you are still comming to terms with.

Answer (score 0):

you need [lein ragtime plugin](https://github.com/weavejester/ragtime) manage the database.

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated